# Script to open xfce4-terminal drop-down and then run a command in that dropped window

Tags: xfce

I am able to write a script which will open an xfce4-terminal window and run a program - I'm interested in using ranger - but I cannot see how to make this work in the **drop-down** window.

eg

```
#! /bin/bash
xfce4-terminal   -e "/bin/bash -c 'ranger'" &
```

works a treat - but this doesn't

```
#! /bin/bash
xfce4-terminal --drop-down  -e "/bin/bash -c 'ranger'" &
```

Could anyone suggest how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work ok

```
#!/bin/bash
xfce4-terminal --tab --drop-down -e ranger
```

and then use a program like xbindkeys to create a shortcut